# Order-independent input archive for boost serialization

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-serialization

I use boost::serialization and like it very much. The only thing, I miss sometimes, is when I want to read configuration input structures from a xml archive. Then it would be nice, if

1. the xml structure could be order-independent and
2. if a object is missing in the xml, the default value of the class will be taken.

Is this principally possible for boost::serialization or do you have already a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I think it's more constructive to show-don't-tell, here's a sample of what I think you're after using Boost Property Tree:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b9bc47d77cbfff1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

struct Config {
    std::string order;
    double independent;
    std::string stuff;

    static Config load_xml(std::istream& from) {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        read_xml(from, pt);

        return {
            pt.get("order", "default property value for order"),
            pt.get("independent", 42.0),
            pt.get("stuff", "no stuff configured")
        };
    }

    void save_xml(std::ostream& to) const {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

        if (!order.empty())   pt.put("order",       order);
        if (independent != 0) pt.put("independent", independent);
        if (!stuff.empty())   pt.put("stuff",       stuff);

        write_xml(to, pt);
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        Config cfg { "order", 999, "stuff" };
        cfg.save_xml(std::cout);
    }

    std::istringstream iss("<independent>3.1415926535897931</independent><IGNORED>stuff</IGNORED><order>LOOK MA</order>");

    Config::load_xml(iss).save_xml(std::cout);
}
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>order</order><independent>999</independent><stuff>stuff</stuff>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>LOOK MA</order><independent>3.1415926535897931</independent><stuff>no stuff configured</stuff>
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialization isn't for this.

Of course you can make the things you serialize order-independent anyways:

```
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

struct MyConfig {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> values;

    template<typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & values;
    }
};
```

The order in which things are read will be irrelevant.

Also, having optional default is something you can already do (hint: it's not related to serialization at all):

```
struct MyConfig {
    std::string const& workingDirectory() {
        return *values.emplace("workingdir", "$HOME").first;
    }

  private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> values;
};
```

Here `workingDirectory()` will return a reference to the value that was deserialized. And if no such value exists, `"$HOME"` will be inserted first.

### HOWEVER

You should consider using [Boost Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) for this scenario. It's much more suited for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right that using a xml parser, like boost property tree, it would be easier to achieve the requirements. However, it would be nice to use boost serialization to avoid parallel structures and data type conversions. Using a map for reading a unordered list has the disadvantage that the data type is fixed, in your example to a string.

Comment: For the record, Boost Property Tree is **not** an XML parser. Have you considered using a `std::map<std::string, boost::variant<std::string, double, bool, ...> >`?

Comment: The problem is that the setting classes are modular, so that a object of a setting class is often another setting class and can also be polymorphic. Therefore, I have many different data types which are not good maintainable using boost variant.

Comment: Maybe you should considering posting the actual question, instead of trickling in more constraints one at a time. I'll consider this question closed for now

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/sena73/ptree_archive) is my experimental boost::serialization archive which is able to serialize to boost::property_tree.

By default generated ptree is created in a way suited for json or info format, but will little modification it can be optimized for xml.

It can load fields in arbitrary order, also additional fields will be ignored (which allows some forward compatibility).

Currently missed field will produce an error. Introducing optional fields with defaults require some additional work.

There is also a [patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/8088) for xml archive which allows to skip unknown fields, but it does not allow arbitrary order or optional fields.